# Website shift effect using jquery or css3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can a website shift effect be done like this website? http://showmyshift.com/# When you click a link, the content flies by and shifts.

I believe they are either using CSS3 or Jquery to do this, how can it be done?

EDIT: I also have no idea what this effect is called, nor have I seen it before.  I'm hoping someone more experienced has seen this effect before and knows what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's just a slider, simply look for a slider that allows linking to specific slides, like [Unslider](http://unslider.com/) (tricky if you don't know what are you doing) or [Owl Carousel](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/) or the millions out there, and simply link each menu item to a slide. You can also use CSS, but for what you say about your knowledge, it's not recommended since it's way more difficult

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: I don't think that sliders are for that case a good solution. I agree, it's a slider in that case. But wouldn't be an ajax call with a jquery animation a lot better? Not to mention the ugly effect if you click click twice the same Link (like home).

Comment: @Quentin : it's a couple links with instructions on how to do it, so it's a proper solution and a proper answer, which was accepted, btw. What I was supposed to tell him? Write your own code?

Comment: @Grief-Code: you're right and as a matter of fact that site IS IN FACT AJAX. But I was trying to provide him with a solution for someone with limited technical knowledge, if I tell him about AJAX he wouldn't know what to do, hence he would end with nothing. Now, he has something. About the double effect, it depends on the script, some scripts don't have that issue. Anyway, I'm kind of "let's solve things" guy rather than "it's not perfect so let's not do it"

Comment: @Fabio — No, you're supposed to tell him *how* to write his own code. If you want to recommend a product, then do so in a comment.